# download file and redirect page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to write a program where after button click page will be redirected and one pdf file will be download. I am writing the following code under the button click event. but it is showing the error.

```
Response.TransmitFile("Filename")
Response.Redirect("~/Redirect.aspx")
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible, because file download will get HTTP status 200 (with file in response). Redirect is 301/302, but cannot contain file in response.

Moreover when modern browser receive a file it does not change the current URL.

If you really want to have such effect you have to create something on client side. For example you can use [jquery file download](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) which has events after download and on error. More on [examples page](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)